# How to restore the the filter on back button using React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

ItemList: renders a list of predefined items.

When you click on an item in the list , you will be redirected to another page containing ItemDetails component and it shows you some details about the item.

when you use the back button on the details page , you will go back to the list page, but the filter will be gone. What can i do to restore the filter? How to restore the the filter on back button using React.

Comment: Hi, please review [ask] and [mre]. You will likely not receive satisfactory answers without more specific details and code.

Answer (score 0):

store your filters in URL (query strings), then by using [query-string](https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-string) you can catch them from URL.

e.g:

***url: /serach?keyword=helloworld?sort=alphabetic***

```
const parsed = queryString.parse(location.search);
console.log(parsed); // {keyword: "helloworld", sort: "alphabetic"}
```

Comment: As we have many filter criteria, we are using post call with request parameters as body.

Comment: @MM this does not matter, in react the routing system is in your own control and did not relate to the back-end... you can store those in an object then pass it as request body or ..... . anyway... if you don't want to use query string, you can store them in state management like context or redux.